# Deleting duplication in list

Tags: python, list

I have the following list,

```
test=[[('x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5'),
  ('x6','x7')],
 [('x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5'),
  ('x6','x7')],
 [('x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5'),
  ('x6','x7','x8')]]
```

I want to delete duplicate element so that I get:

```
[[('x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5'),
  ('x6','x7')],
 [('x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5'),
  ('x6','x7','x8')]]
```

I tried:

```
list(dict.fromkeys(test))
```

and

```
list(set(test))
```

for both of which method I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I wonder what am I doing wrong and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the lists within the list are not *hashable* and thus can not be added into a `dict` (as keys) or `set`. Instead, you could convert those to `tuples`, or to their `repr` if they could have nested lists, and use *those* as the key and the lists themselves as the values in a `dict`.

```
>>> d = {tuple(x): x for x in test}                                         
>>> list(d.values())                                                        
[[('x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5'), ('x6', 'x7')],
 [('x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5'), ('x6', 'x7', 'x8')]]
```

Other than `set`, this also preserves the original order of the list (at least with newer versions of Python). For older versions, you can use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

Before inserting to set make sure you convert list to tuple. Then you can convert it back to list:

```
test=[[('x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5'), ('x6','x7')],
      [('x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5'), ('x6','x7')],
      [('x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5'), ('x6','x7','x8')]]

from pprint import pprint

pprint([list(i) for i in set(tuple(i) for i in test)])
```

Prints:

```
[[('x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5'), ('x6', 'x7', 'x8')],
 [('x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5'), ('x6', 'x7')]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```py
print([i for n,i in enumerate(test) if i not in test[:n]])
```

Output:

```py
[[('x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5'), ('x6', 'x7')],
[('x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5'), ('x6', 'x7', 'x8')]]
```

Comment: I just check it, so @tobias_k? Did I miss anything?

Comment: Did you really? I just tried with "only" 100,000 elements and it's still not finished. (What I meant is: This is O(n²) and thus not really applicable to longer lists. For shorter lists it is fine, but still a bit wasteful.)

Comment: ohh you are correct @tobias_k, I just miss one zero. Yes it took very long time to execute. But for some small list this method should okay? right? Because we can do the same thing in different ways.